Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Unable to list objects in S3 bucket "s3_bucket" with prefix "env:/":
I'm trying to init the backend in Terraform
this is the backend.tf
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    dynamodb_table = "cpf-tflock-dev"
    bucket         = "s3_bucket"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
  }
}

terraform init

Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Unable to list objects in S3 bucket "s3_bucket" with prefix "env:/": operation error S3: ListObjectsV2, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , HostID: , request send failed, Get "http://s3_bucket.localhost:4566/?list-type=2&max-keys=1000&prefix=env%3A%2F": dial tcp: lookup s3_bucket.localhost: no such host

I'm trying to init the backend in terraform
The backend.tf file is inside environment/dev/backend.tf
I'm trying to execute the terraform init in the dev folder. When I move the backend.tf to the root of the project it's working fine. I'm using localstack for testing

I am facing the same error for some reason. The API keys have the relevant permissions though.

s3_bucket.localhost is not a globally-resolvable hostname, so it will work only if you've configured your local computer to resolve that hostname.
The LocalStack project offers a domain name localhost.localstack.cloud which is currently configured to always resolve to the local loopback address 127.0.0.1. If you use localhost.localstack.cloud instead of just localhost as your localstack domain then that should resolve as expected.

I think this issue is the answer. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/34223
In short, try adding the access keys as parameters in the backend S3 provider.
